# C# container for storing permutations

Tags: c#, containers

I am looking for an unusual c# container library for use in a
scheduling search algorithm. The search algorithm evaluates solutions
identified by different permutations and looking for the best solution it can
find. As part of the algorithm it needs to remember previously
'visited' solutions so it can avoid ending up in a circular loop. Hence I
need a container which is indexed by a permutation. The permutation is
an array of size N holding the values 0 through to N-1 in a 'random'
order.

The container only needs to store a Boolean indicating the location has
been visited. It needs to be a quick lookup, it needs to make
efficient use of memory.

I suspect a tree may be optimal ... But only if there is an existing
library as this issue is also constrained by my available time to implement it.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash set to quickly look up permuations.

Create a class to use as key in the hash set, and an equality comparer for the class, something like:

```
publc class Permutation {

  private int[] _values;

  public Permutation(int[] values) {
    _values = values;
  }

  public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Permuation> {

    public int GetHashCode(Permuation x) {
      int code = 0;
      foreach (int value in x._values) {
        code = code * 251 + value;
      }
      return code;
    }

    public bool Equals(Permuation x, Permuation y) {
      if (x._values.Length != y._values.Length) return false;
      for (int i=0; i<x._values.Length; i++) {
        if (x._values[i] != y._values[i]) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

  }

}
```

Then you can create a hash set that uses the class as key, and it's comparer to evaluate equalness:

```
var permutations = new HashSet<Permutation>(new Permutation.Comparer());
```

Now you can create permutation objects and put in the set, and test for them:

```
permuations.Add(new Permuation(new int[]{1,2,3}));

Permutation lookingFor = new Permutation(new int[]{1,2,3});
bool exists = permutations.Contains(lookgFor); // returns true

Permutation lookingFor = new Permutation(new int[]{1,3,2});
bool exists = permutations.Contains(lookgFor); // returns false
```

Comment: Yep, hashset is one of the obvious solutions. OP mentions memory efficiency though, so it is not clear whether he can afford keeping all visited permutations in memory as is. Good advice, anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, with code too. I am mindful that this requires N multiplications every time the hash is calculated and multiplications are relatively expensive. If a tree is used then there is no need for this as it only requires comparisons. Furthermore, the number of comparisons will be significantly less than 'N' as this will be a very sparse array. I believe that a tree should be as memory efficient if not more than the hash. For these reasons I am currently hoping to find a tree based container. Regards

Comment: @Howard May: Multiplications aren't more expensive. They once were, but not with modern processors. I just made a quick test, and I can't measure any performance difference at all between addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Howard, in a tree, the number of comparisons can be smaller than *N* if there isn't a match. But if there is a match, you have to do all *N* comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a trade-off. It's either speed or memory. Permutations can be converted to indexes as described [here](http://home.tiac.net/~cri/2001/perm2index.html), but it's costly. On the other hand you don't need to convert them. From what you wrote, I understand that you algorithm works on permutations so it "knows" them. In this case it can just store them (visited) as is (say, in a list or a hashset). In this case you don't spend additional time on "compressing" a permutation into an index, but you need to make sure you have enough memory.

Another mental exercise that is worth doing, is sizing up how many different permutations your algorithm need to store "visited" state for. This way you can more realisticly decide whether you need to save memory, or you can choose a faster performing option.

Also some times ago, I googled "c# permutations" and was able to find a number of combinatoric libraries, whether they provide what you want or not I don't know, I suggest you look at them and see if they can suit you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [hash table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) might be what you are looking for. The lookup time is constant, and the time to add a new element to the container is also constant (as long as you don't "overfill" it, then it takes linear time to increase the containers capacity).

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents: [have a look at this code](http://pastebin.com/MwKVMnde)

The given link contains a permutations container implemented with a tree, this means fast lookup and fair memory usage.

Maybe `GetPermutations()` methods could be improved using a `Stack<T>`, but it is left as an exercise to the reader :D